# Is init.d "safe" enough to use or should i use `runit` or `daemontools` on a server

Tags: startup, upstart, services, init.d, runit

I am looking to deploy my application on a server on which I would have no access in the future.  I would like to have an indication of start-up errors generated by my program in particular and the system in general.

I have never used any of those supervision tools and wonder what added value those would bring in?

Is relying on the Debian/Ubuntu built-in init scheme not a good idea?

Comment: Just to clarify, scripts from the init.d directory (the legacy init) are not supervised, they are simply started/stopped with the system. You probably wanted to refer to Upstart, Ubuntu's new init system.

Comment: never knew about upstart until you have mentioned it. many thanks. looking at its home page right now.

Answer (score 2):

If you will have no access to the server in the future, there should be someone else that is able to monitor the application and the server. No automated solution can solve all possible issues.

However, solutions such as [Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) can help a lot in some cases, by automatically restarting your application if for example it crashed or is using too much memory.

If your application is very simple and stable, a simple init.d or upstart script to start it on server startup can work.